# Angular ngStyle Dynamic Styling Element with ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, styling, angular-directive, angular-template

I am developing dynamically style element feature in App server authentication and database search engine.

> When `searchNoResult`, UI is:

[image]

> When click the button triggering `execSearch()` event -> `searchSuccess` is true and template `searchSuccessColor` takes effect (text backgroundColor turns pink).
>   However, I can’t seem to get the color dynamically styled:

[image]

> I tried setting the template as below but doesn't work:

```
<button class="button" 
    [disabled] = "!enableSearch"
    (click) = "execSearch()">Search State</button>
    <div *ngIf = "searchSuccess; then searchSuccessColor else searchNoResult"></div>
<ng-template #searchNoResult>
    <p>{{ stateSearchResult }}</p>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #searchSuccessColor>
    <div [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: 'pink'}"></div>
        <p>{{ stateSearchResult }}</p>
</ng-template>
```

> I tired component method as below but doesn't work:

```
  setColor() {
    return this.searchSuccess === true ? 'pink' : 'black';
  }
```

Can someone help to identify what goes wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the else block is used only to color the background, then it could be skipped entirely using `[style.background-color]` and the ternary operator. Try the following

```html
<div [style.background-color]="searchSuccess ? 'pink' : ''"><p>{{ stateSearchResult }}</p></div>
```

Or if you wish to use `ngStyle` (maybe to include more styles), it would be

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': searchSuccess ? 'pink' : ''}"><p>{{ stateSearchResult }}</p></div>
```

Or you could also use `ngClass` to conditionally include CSS selectors.

app.component.css

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<div [ngClass]="{highlight: searchSuccess}"><p>{{ stateSearchResult }}</p></div>
```

#### Update: Use a variable defined in the controller

If you wish not to hard-code the color value, you could try to define a variable in the controller that holds the color value.

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  backgroundColor = 'pink';

  // button `click` event handler
  execSearch() {
    ...
    this.backgroundColor = searchSuccess ? 'pink' : 'black';
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<div [style.background-color]="backgroundColor">
  <p>{{ stateSearchResult }}</p>
</div>

<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': backgroundColor}">
  <p>{{ stateSearchResult }}</p>
</div>
```

Notice the lack of single quotes surrounding the `backgroundColor` here. It denotes the variable in the controller. The single quoted values like `'pink'` denote the string literals.

**ngClass**

CSS

```css
.highlight-pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.highlight-black {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

Template

```html
<div [ngClass]="searchSuccess ? 'highlight-pink' : 'highlight-black'">
  <p>{{ stateSearchResult }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: WORKS!  Let's be more OOP:

Comment: I replace the hardcoded ```pink``` with method ```setColor()``` as ```<button class="button" 
    [disabled] = "!enableSearch"
    (click) = "execSearch()">Search State</button>
<div [style.background-color]="searchSuccess ? setColor() : ''"><p>{{ stateSearchResult }}</p></div>```.  How can I remove the ```[style.background-color]``` ?  I tried `[ngStyle]` but the color is off again. I want to obfuscate the content of template.  How can I do that?

Comment: If you aren't controlling the change detection strategy, try not to call functions like `setColor()` in an event binding. And despite any obfuscation, users could always see the sources in the browser console debugger.

Comment: @FionaChen: I've updated the answer to use controller variables.

Comment: Thanks! What is the best practice to control the Styling like `font`, `size`, `color`, `position`...etc ?

Comment: There isn't a specific best-practice, it boils down to the use case. If a very simple single style need to be modified, use `[style....]`, if you wish to modify a set of simple styles directly, use `[ngStyle]`. If you wish to use complicated set of styles (like in your case `font`, `size`, `color`, `position`...) based on conditions, use `[ngClass]`.

Comment: I appreciate your great insight !!